# Differences between "no sooner had" and "no sooner than"

Tags: inversion, time

> **No sooner had** we started the work than he closed the door.

Can I use **No sooner than** instead of **No sooner had**? When can it be used? If I use **No sooner than** instead of **No sooner had**, will the meaning of a sentence remain same?

Comment: Wait a minute. Do you want to repeat ***than*** in the sentence? Do you think it makes sense?

Comment: It's either: "No sooner had we started than he closed the door" or "No sooner than we had started, he closed the door."

Comment: I agree with @Jim, but is the "had" grammatically necessary here?

Comment: "No sooner" not very commonly used in American English these days. A more popular phrasing is "as soon as". So you could write, "As soon as we started the work, he closed the door".

Comment: @Era - What exactly do you mean by "is 'had' grammatically necessary here"?  I'm not sure what alternative you're suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase is **no sooner had**, which means "just as (something was done)": "**No sooner had** we walked outside, it started to rain", which is equivalent to "**just as** we walked outside, it started to rain". Which, for me, has a different feel than "**as soon as** we walked outside", though the meaning in all three are equivalent. From my experience, **no sooner had** is a bit more literary (rhythmic) and has the feeling of an unexpected coincidence.  **No sooner than** does not sound correct.